# How can I query a PHP script with curl through a Proxy?

Tags: networking, apache2, php, proxy, curl

I like to build a Proxy checker with a self hosted PHP backend. While testing I found this Proxy: `207.154.231.211:8080` that shows a strange behaviour.

It is possible to reach similar services like: `ip-api.com`, `sbjudge3.com/azenv.php` or `proxyjudge.us/azenv.php`

with `curl -x 207.154.231.211:8080 <url>`

At the same time it is not possible to reach my very basic PHP script which I hosted on `dnsserver.icu` for testing purposes.

I can't find a reason for this. There neighter seem to be any special response headers nor a specific domain or webserver that could cause this error.

What is the reason? What is different between the behaviour of my service and the ones I listed above? I appreciate if anyone could investigate further on this.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]